# d3js display animated text into pie charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have 3 pie charts that get loaded with an animation.
Each of this chart, has a text inside, the percent number, that one chart is loaded follow the animation and start the counting from 0% to tot%

I was able to show the text in one pie chart, but when i adapt the code to be used from 3 pie charts, i cannot find the way to display 3 text.
I loop trought the 3 div and trhough the 3 percent number, i can see the correct percent number in the console, but then nothing get displayed inside the pie chart :/

I'm new to d3 so it might be much easier then what i can see.

```
app.numbers = {
    calcPerc : function(percent) {
      return [percent, 100-percent];
    },

    drawDonutChart : function(el, percent, width, height, text_y) {
      width = typeof width !== undefined ? width : 290; //width
      height = typeof height !== undefined ? height : 290; //height
      text_y = typeof text_y !== undefined ? text_y : "-.10em";

      var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
      var pie = d3.pie().sort(null);

      var dataset = {
        lower: this.calcPerc(0),
        upper: this.calcPerc(percent)
      }
      //this.percents = percent;

      this.arc = d3.arc()
            .innerRadius(radius - 20)
            .outerRadius(radius);

      var svg = d3.select(el).append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

      var path = svg.selectAll("path")
            .data(pie(dataset.lower))
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d, i) { return "color" + i })
            .attr("d", this.arc)
            .each(function(d) { this._currentArc = d; }); // store the initial values

      // add text in the center of the donut
      this.text = svg.append('text')
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("dy", text_y)
                .attr("d", percent)

      if (typeof(percent) === "string") {
        this.text.text(percent);
      } else {

        var self = this;
        var timeout = setTimeout( function () {
          clearTimeout(timeout);

          path = path.data(pie(dataset.upper)); // update the data
          path.transition().ease(d3.easeExp).duration('500').attrTween("d", function(a){
            var progress = 0;
            var format = d3.format(".0%");
            // Store the displayed angles in _currentArc.
            // Then, interpolate from _currentArc to the new angles.
            // During the transition, _currentArc is updated in-place by d3.interpolate.
            var i  = d3.interpolate(this._currentArc, a);
            var i2 = d3.interpolate(progress, percent);
            this._currentArc = i(0);

            return function(t) {
              $(self.text).each(function(){
                $(this).text( format(i2(t) / 100) );
              });
              return self.arc(i(t));
            };

          }); // redraw the arcs

        }, 200);
      }
    },

    init : function(){

      $('.donut').each( function() {
        var percent = $(this).data('donut');

        app.numbers.drawDonutChart(
          this,
          percent,
          190,
          190,
          ".35em"
        );
      })
    }
  }
}

// initialize pie on scroll
window.onscroll = function() {
  app.numbers.init();
}
```

Html:

```
<section class="row numbers section-bkg section-bkg--blue">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="donut" data-donut="42"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="donut" data-donut="12"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="donut" data-donut="86"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Any idea how should i display the text?
i'm pretty sure the problem is here:

```
$(self.text).each(function(){
  $(this).text( format(i2(t) / 100) );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite mixing jQuery and D3 never being a good idea (try to avoid it), it seems that that was not the problem. The problem seems to be the fact that you're changing the text inside the factory, using a previously assigned `self`.

One solution (without changing your code too much, certainly there are better ways to refactor it) is getting the texts based on the current `<path>`:

```
var self2 = this;//this is the transitioning path
return function(t) {
    d3.select(self2.parentNode).select("text").text(format(i2(t) / 100));
    return self.arc(i(t));
};
```

Here is your code (without jQuery):

```js
var app = {};

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)

app.numbers = {
  calcPerc: function(percent) {
    return [percent, 100 - percent];
  },

  drawDonutChart: function(el, percent, width, height, text_y) {
    width = typeof width !== undefined ? width : 290; //width
    height = typeof height !== undefined ? height : 290; //height
    text_y = typeof text_y !== undefined ? text_y : "-.10em";

    var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
    var pie = d3.pie().sort(null);

    var dataset = {
        lower: this.calcPerc(0),
        upper: this.calcPerc(percent)
      }
      //this.percents = percent;

    this.arc = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(radius - 20)
      .outerRadius(radius);

    var svg = d3.select(el).append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var path = svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(pie(dataset.lower))
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color(i)
      })
      .attr("d", this.arc)
      .each(function(d) {
        this._currentArc = d;
      }); // store the initial values

    // add text in the center of the donut
    this.text = svg.append('text')
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("dy", text_y)
      .attr("d", percent)

    this.text.text(percent);

    var self = this;

    path = path.data(pie(dataset.upper)); // update the data
    path.transition().ease(d3.easeExp).duration(1000).attrTween("d", function(a) {
      var progress = 0;
      var format = d3.format(".0%");
      // Store the displayed angles in _currentArc.
      // Then, interpolate from _currentArc to the new angles.
      // During the transition, _currentArc is updated in-place by d3.interpolate.
      var i = d3.interpolate(this._currentArc, a);
      var i2 = d3.interpolate(progress, percent);
      this._currentArc = i(0);

      var self2 = this;

      return function(t) {
        d3.select(self2.parentNode).select("text").text(format(i2(t) / 100));
        return self.arc(i(t));
      };

    }); // redraw the arcs
  },

  init: function() {

    d3.selectAll('.donut').each(function() {
      var percent = d3.select(this).node().dataset.donut;

      app.numbers.drawDonutChart(
        this,
        percent,
        190,
        190,
        ".35em"
      );
    })
  }
}

app.numbers.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<section class="row numbers section-bkg section-bkg--blue">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="donut" data-donut="42"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="donut" data-donut="12"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="donut" data-donut="86"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: that's it!thanks also for the explanation and better practice. I like the idea of avoid jQuery. If you have time can you tell me how would you have refactor it? Or maybe if you have links to some read i could do to understand how to structure my d3 code better, please let me know :)